# Inconsistent behaviour between in RichTextBox.Select with SubString method

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, substring

I am developing a Windows Form application. I use `RichTextBox.LoadFile` method to load text from a file and highlight some portion of the text. The text in the file contains return characters.

Suppose that I want to highlight `the highlight`. First I find the `startIndex` and the `length` of the `the highlight` part, then use `RichTextBox.Select(startIndex, length)` and give some color to it.

When I use `SubString` method, I can find the correct text. But when I apply the same value of `startIndex` and `length` to `Select` method, the highlighted part becomes `[space][space][space]the highli`. It looks the `Select` method takes some return characters into account and cause some problem.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Do you know if the file contains the usual windows sequences `"\r\n"`, that is `(char)0x0D` followed by `(char)0x0A`, or just single `"\r"` or single `"\n"` for each "return"?

Comment: Hello Jeppe. The original file contains `\r` and `\n`. It is a text file processed in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the `Find()` method of `RichTextBox`:

```
int nextStartIndex;
public void Find(string keyword){
   int i = richTextBox1.Find(keyword, nextStartIndex, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
   if(i != -1) {
      nextStartIndex = i + keyword.Length;          
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first time i hear about it and i use the `richTextBox` a lot. try to use `SubString` to find the substring you want on the `richTextBox.Text` instead of the string from the file. if you are already do it try to check the return number from substring method and see if it reference the right location.

also, please share your code please, i want to see it for myself. if it is a .net problem then i need to go over my work...

Comment: If I use richTextBox.Text.Substring(startIndex, length), I can get the correct result. But if then I use richTextBox(startIndex, length). It does not select correctly. It adds some spaces like what I described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I "Search" for a specific text in a RichTextBox then highlight it to RED

```
private void ColoritRed(RichTextBox rtb, string StringToHighlight)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        string searchText = StringToHighlight;
        pos = rtb.Find(searchText);
        while (pos != -1)
        {
            if (rtb.SelectedText == searchText)
            {
                this.ActiveControl = rtb;
                rtb.SelectionStart = pos;
                rtb.SelectionLength = searchText.Length;
                rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            }
            pos = rtb.Find(searchText, pos + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
        }
```