# RichTextBox SelectionStart offset with linebreaks

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm using a RichTextBox for coloured text. Let's assume I want to use different colours for different portions of the text. This is working fine so far.

I'm currently having a problem with the SelectionStart property of the RichTextBox. I've set some text to the Text property of the RichTextBox. If the text contains `\r\n\r\n` the SelectionStart Position won't match the position of characters with the assigned String.

Small example (WinformsApplication. Form with a RichTextBox):

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        String sentence1 = "This is the first sentence.";
        String sentence2 = "This is the second sentence";

        String text = sentence1 + "\r\n\r\n" + sentence2;
        int start1 = text.IndexOf(sentence1);
        int start2 = text.IndexOf(sentence2);

        this.richTextBox1.Text = text;

        String subString1 = text.Substring(start1, sentence1.Length);
        String subString2 = text.Substring(start2, sentence2.Length);

        bool match1 = (sentence1 == subString1); // true
        bool match2 = (sentence2 == subString2); // true

        this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start1;
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength = sentence1.Length;
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

        this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start2;
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength = sentence2.Length;
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;

    }
```

The RichTextBox looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the first two characters of the second sentence are not coloured. This is the result of an offset produced by `\r\n\r\n`.

What is the reason for this? Should I use another control for colouring text?
How do I fix the problem in a reliable way? I've tried replacing the `"\r\n\r\n"`with a String.Empty, but that produces other offset problem.

**Related question**:
[Inconsistent behaviour between in RichTextBox.Select with SubString method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248176/inconsistent-behaviour-between-in-richtextbox-select-with-substring-method)

Comment: A pretty 'cludgey' way would be to determine whether the 2nd substring, in this case, is preceded by those characters throwing your offset off, and amend your substring parameters accordingly. I won't post this as an answer by the way as I'm holding out to see 'proper' ways of doing this. +1 for good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness (I'll stick to linepogls answer for now):
 I've found another way to get indices for the SelectionStart property. The RichTextBox offers a [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab8wkhy.aspx) method, that can be used to retrieve index positions based on a specified string.

Be aware of the fact, that the text you want to highlight might not be unique and occur multiple times. You can use an overload to specify a start position for the search.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the sequence `\r\n` counts for one character only when doing selections. You can do the measurements in a copy of the string where all `\r\n` are replaced by `\n`.

Comment: Seems to solve my problem =) Do you know why the RichTextBox is behaving this way?